# weird xib file to nib conversion issue

Tags: iphone, xib, loadnibnamed

I was trying to add a new view controller on Xcode 4.5.2, i made the xib file to be compatible to 5.1, started playing around with it and suddenly noticed that this custom table view cell is not getting loaded at all, it was always creating a crash on load.

> [self.cellNib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];

I started checking the .app file which is getting created, i am able to see that except for this new custom table view cell nib files all the other xibs are in **"nib"** extension. what setting can make this xib file to be converted to nib like others.

Answer (score 2):

Go to file inspector then select identity inspector as following:
[image]

In class select your particular class for that you want to add nib file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I got the problem, they way nib file was added as reference to the main project, i was just drag dropping form the sub project to the main target.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your custom class name in the field of Custom class 'Class' field.

Answer (score 0):

All my view controllers and their xibs are in another project which is reference in the main project, the problem was with my methodology of reference to the main target. i was just pulling the xib file from the referenced project to the main target. the actual way of doing it is like this

touch the main target's xcodeprojfile, choose the target, build phases, in copy resource bundle press '+' and then add the xib file. Thanks to @vishal for his guess on the problem.